# Почему так нельзя говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Добрый день, интуитивно понимаю,но не могу грамотно и аргументированно объяснить человеку, почему нельзя сказать "регистрация на учете по квотированию"? Подскажите, пожалуйста, с ссылкой на правила.

Answer (score 2):

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

Существует закон "О квотировании рабочих мест", который обязывает предприятия принимать на работу инвалидов или платить в  казну деньги. Если этого не происходит,  предприятие обязано  встать на учет в Центре квотирования в течение месяца после государственной регистрации этого предприятия.

Действительно, нельзя сказать "регистрация на учете по квотированию".

Сочетание "учет по квотированию" существует, например: снятие с учета по квотированию, постановка на учет по квотированию.

Но не существует сочетания "регистрация на учете чего-либо", поэтому надо сказать: "постановка (организации) на учет по квотированию" или "регистрация для учета по квотированию".